# How can I choose the rights firmware of Tomato when I do not have access to the router?

Tags: wireless-router, firmware, tomato

I have an old router running an old version of Tomato and I want to upgrade it.

The problem is that on the web interface it reports a generic version: `WRT54G/WRT54GS/WRT54GL` but the latest tomato build has 4 bin files matching this generic description:

- WRT54G_WRT54GL.bin
- WRT54GS.bin
- WRT54GSv4.bin
- WRTSL54GS.bin

There is no direct access to the router, so you cannot check it's version.

Comment: Are you upgrading your neighbor's router again?

Comment: Seriously - does the current tomato version tell you what version it is?  perhaps you can extrapolate from there.  My dd-wrt rev tells me whic firware I'm using.  Other than that, maybe you can figure it out by checking features such as ram size, etc.

Comment: Almost right :) The webpage shows the string I put in the question, not the exact bin used by it.

Comment: Look on the bottom of the router. It's labeled with the model and version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe most of the WRT54G series routers differ in

- RAM capacity
- flash capacity
- wireless chipset

So if you can find out all three from an information page you could deduce what router model you are working with.  I don't have a Tomato-based router here to test and tell you where to go exactly.

You probably could find out the chipset by telneting/SSHing into the device and performing an `lsmod` - look for a driver for the wifi.  RAM capacity can be figured out with a simple `free` command, and flash capacity can be easily deduced with `df` or `mount`.  Assuming the utilites are there in the Tomato build.

Not sure if the chipset is terribly important if Tomato is already working on it.  Flash capacity is going to be the attribute that is important, because if you flash a firmware that is too big you'll need physical access to recover.